# Apache Camel: File Component in Linux environment; Polling Fails

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration

I am using a file component as

```
file:\\orderLocations
```

to read messages.
Deploying my Camel Routing Application in a UNIX/ Linux environment.
On deployment, each Poll gives this message

```
 Cannot poll as directory does not exists or its not a directory: /orderLocations
```

Although I see that a folder with name

```
\orderLocations
```

is created. However, it does not poll messages from there.

Kindly guide the right way to use File Component in UNIX/LINUX environment

Comment: Use unix slashes / in the endpoint. And mind if you need to poll from the root dir, then use a single slash, eg `file:/orderLocations`. And make sure the user has permission to read from that directory.

Comment: Thank You @ClausIbsen. I was also able to just use file:orderLocations. It created a folder with the name orderLocations and it polled messages from there. Will also try the unix slashes /

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring DSL in camel as per below for respective OS

**For Linux/Unix**

```
<from uri="file:/user/tempdir?delete=true"/>
```

**For Windows**

```
<from uri="file://user/tempdir?delete=true"/>
```

Comment: Is this true?  Does it default to C:/ in Windows? It doesn't seem to.